# Evaluate function giving error 2029 using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate

Evaluate is throwing error 2029 (#NAME).

The project is using Census procedures to allocate seats in the House of Representatives for any given number of house members (currently 435).  There are a number of proposals to expand the size of the House. I'm investigating budget and economic implications.

My workbook has a sheet named PVC. I'm trying to find the maximum value in column E (number of seats allocated to a given state) for a value in column C (two-letter state abbreviations).

I have removed quite a few lines.
I have experimented with a user-defined function MaxIf().

```vb
Sub CountSeatsEval()

  Dim lNoSeats, lG2, lastrow, lStateRow, lStateSeats, lStateNo As Long
  Dim sFileName, sPathName, sFunction, sSearchValue, sSearchState As String
  Dim sStateAbbr, vStateSeats As Variant
  Dim wsSource, wsTarget As Worksheet
  Dim rMaxRange, rSearchValue, rSearchState As Range
  Dim rLookup1 As Range
  Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PVC")
  'Following line is to make life easy temporarily
  Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PVC")
  lNoSeats = wsSource.Range("G2").Value
...
  'Copy and paste G2 to replace formula with value
  wsTarget.Range("G2").Copy
  wsTarget.Range("G2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
  lastrow = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
...
  sSearchValue = "'PVC'!E2:$E$" & lastrow
  sSearchState = "'PVC'!$C$6"
...
   sStateAbbr = "CA"
   lStateRow = 6
   vStateSeats = Evaluate("IF((MAXIFS(sSearchValue, sSearchState, sSearchState))>0,(MAXIFS(sSearchValue, sSearchState, sSearchState)),1)")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sSearchValue` and `sSearchState` are VBA local variables:

> ```
> Dim sFileName, sPathName, sFunction, sSearchValue, sSearchState As String
> ```

Note that this statement declares `sSearchState` as a `String`, and then leaves all other 4 variables without a declared type, making them implicit `Variant` variables (see [VariableTypeNotDeclared](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/VariableTypeNotDeclared) Rubberduck inspection details).

Being local VBA variables, they live in the VBA runtime context, and Excel doesn't have the slightest idea about their existence - so you get a `#NAME?` error:

[image: immediate pane showing CVErr(xlErrName) outputting 'Error 2029']

In Excel you get a `#NAME?` error whenever you try to evaluate a formula that contains a name that Excel cannot resolve in the current context.

So you need to have VBA evaluate the variables' values *before* you send the resulting expression over to Excel's calculation engine; you can do this by splitting up the string and using the *concatenation* operator (`&`):

```
vStateSeats = wsTarget.Evaluate("IF((MAXIFS(" & sSearchValue & "," & sSearchState & "," & sSearchState & "))>0,(MAXIFS(" & sSearchValue & "," & sSearchState & "," & sSearchState & ")),1)")
```

Unqualified, `Evaluate` will invoke `[_Global].Evaluate`, which is essentially `Application.Evaluate`, which may or may not produce the desired results - by qualifying it with a specific `Worksheet` object, the formula evaluates in the context of that worksheet.

Comment: Helpful hints to `Evaluate` +:) - It might be worth noting that executing a *qualified* `wsTarget.Evaluate()` upon a `sSearchValue` address prefixed by `'PVC'!...` seems to be sort of redundance; on the other hand an unqualified evaluation (regarding all caveats) would need at least the addition of something like `wsTarget.Range("...",External:=True)`

Comment: correcting missing `.Address`... `wsTarget.Range("...").Address(False,False,External:=True)`

Comment: Very helpful. I thought for sure I had checked the variable definitions.  (I thought the compile step was supposed to find errors like that?) Even more thanks for clarifying how Evaluate works. Extremely educational and useful.

Comment: Another good tip for the elderly, infrequent visitor!

Comment: Addendum. Just learned Excel limits file name length to 218 characters including the full path. Guess we’re back to CP/M 8.3 names. Source: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3]